# how to set variables in a php include file?

Tags: php, variables, include, initialization

I have a set of variables that are set outside the target php include file, how would i set them in the target php include file.  Example:

```
<?php
  $fname = "david";
?>
```

Now how would I set $fname in another php file?

Comment: Which file is included in which? Can you give a more complete example?

Comment: well teh code show above includes the php file where i want to set $fname.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your other PHP file you would do:

```
<?php
  $fname = "david";
?>
```

This answers your question directly, but I would hazard a guess that you actually want to have access to variables that are set in a file that is included into your current file or something along those lines.

So

File1.php:

```
<?php
  $fname = "david";
?>
```

File2.php

```
<?php
require_once 'File1.php';
echo $fname;
```

Would result in `david` being printed to screen.

Comment: exactly. Because I'm trying to save the user input in another php file's variables.  How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use it directly.

$fname = "your value";

Answer (score 0):

The PHP docs have [an article](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) about variable scopes.

The global variable scope is shared across all included and required files. In your example, once you've defined $fname globally, all other PHP lines executed afterwards can access $fname even if they're in different files.

Example: if a.php is:

```
<?php
  $fname = "david";
?>
```

and b.php is:

```
<?php
  $fname = "sarah";
  include 'a.php';
  // $fname is now "david"
?>
```

then executing b.php would define $fname as "sarah", then redefine it as "david" (through a.php).