# Weird Include file is ignored

Tags: php

I have an include file hat has one environment variable:

```
<?php

    $my_env = "D";

?>
```

I would like to include this file in PHP page(s) within sub-folders in the directory where this file is stored.

Right now, when I do

```
<?php

    # includes
    include_once '../environment.php';

    # other code ...

?>
```

The files do not recognize the value I am trying to pass.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try doing a require('../environment.php'); and see if you get any errors

Comment: Take a look at this, and try using require_once() instead of include_once(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483896/how-to-set-variables-in-a-php-include-file

Comment: What is the return value for include_once? var_dump(include_once '../environment.php');

Comment: Is `environment.php` located 1 directory below where you are executing the code?

Comment: Note, you probably don't want to call this an "environment variable" because that term has special meaning, and this variable isn't it.

Comment: Well this is more just an illustration to ASK the question not necessarily a prod / dev implementation.

Comment: Well if you not getting data from included file that mean File Path Is Wrong. Try to echoing somthing and see if output comes. Use require_once instead of include_once.

Comment: OK now, every file in the sub-folders have a line that reads require_once "../environment.php"; but I am still getting 'failed to open stream' when the file is located just up one folder.

Comment: your orginal code is correct, you can use the varibale on another php file using include once. The problem is with your directory path/file path and file name. So check pah and file name post your file structure.

Comment: Well ok then but if I change it to include_once(../environment.php) I am still located one folder above the sub-folders. I am not sure why it fails to open stream.

Comment: Add the file system layout so we can see at what level the files/folders are at.

Comment: one folder with a env.php in the root. Four (could be any number really...) sub-folders in the directory, each containing an include line trying to bring in the variables in the file one directory above them. Pretty basic...

Comment: `../` is not basic in anyway. That is back one directory. `../../` would be back two directors. Please provide us your exact file structure...

Comment: I have one file in the root directory and files in sub-directories off of the root. I am trying to include the file in the root parent folder. How is that NOT basic? It's up one folder from the sub-directories...